# XOR mask in java android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xor

User enter code word and text to encrypt and program should put XOR mask - code on text - and turn back to normal , but it just put on mask and dont turn back to normal look , why ?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        code = etCode.getText().toString();
        text = etText.getText().toString(); 

        while(code.length()<text.length()){
            code+=code;
        }
        char[] Ccode = code.toCharArray();
        char[] Ctext = text.toCharArray();

        for(i=0;i<Ctext.length;i++){
            Ctext[i]^=Ccode[i];
        }

        rezult=Ctext.toString();

        for(i=0;i<Ctext.length;i++){
            Ctext[i]^=Ccode[i];
        }
        rezult+="\n";
        rezult+=Ctext.toString();
        tvMain.setText(rezult);
        }
    });
```

if I enter `code : code  , text : text` 
it shows:

```
[C@40527808
[C@40527808
```

Answer (score 2):

You output the address of the array. You want the content. 
Arrays have not useful `toString()` mwthod.

change

```
rezult=Ctext.toString();
```

to

```
rezult=new String(Ctext);
```

same for

```
rezult+=Ctext.toString();
```

=>

```
rezult+=new String(Ctext);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the default `toString()` operation on arrays is to convert to an internal identifier, which is what you're seeing. Try using:

```
rezult = new String(Ctext);
...
rezult += new String(Ctext);
```

or, depending on what you want to display (since it's not clear to me that `Ctext` always contains displayable characters):

```
rezult = Arrays.toString(Ctext);
...
rezult += Arrays.toString(Ctext);
```

This will give you a comma-separated array of character values, surrounded by square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use toString() to convert a char array to String.

Use `tvMain.setText(new String(Ctext));`